# TypeScript possible error changing from If statement to conditional operator

Tags: typescript, conditional-operator

In this example of TS that appears [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html):

```
function padLeft(padding: number | string, input: string) {
  if (typeof padding === "number") {
    return " ".repeat(padding) + input;
                        
(parameter) padding: number
  }
  return padding + input;
           
(parameter) padding: string
}
```

Cannot be replace with this code:

```
function padLeft(padding: number | string, input: string) {
    return typeof padding === "number"?" ".repeat(padding) + input:padding + input;
}
```

Gives this error:

```
error TS2550: Property 'repeat' does not exist on type '" "'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

     return typeof padding === "number"?" ".repeat(padding) + input:padding + input;
```

It appears to be a TS error: the " " is a string and " ".repeat() is a method of the string object.
Can anyone help me clarifying this? Thank you.

Comment: "Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later." Well, did you try this yet?

Comment: I think you're misidentifying the issue entirely; the original code at the top would *also* fail for you for the same reason: your TS config is targeting an older version of JS where strings are not known to have a `repeat()` method.  It has nothing to do with replacing `if` with a conditional operator.  I think maybe this question should be closed as "not reproducible or caused by a typo" since I don't imagine anyone else with this problem would find this question when searching.

Comment: You are correct! Using the option --target es2015 in compiler solved the issue. Thank you.